# How to call a method with arguement in a test class

Tags: unit-test

```
private void insertRawData(LocationSOHMapSummary locSohMapObj) {
        
        List<Dummy_Object__c> accToTerrList = new List<Dummy_Object__c>();
        
        for(LocationSOHMapDetail detObj : locSohMapObj.LocSohDetails) {
            if(detObj.Sales_Organization_Code == cs_SalesOrgCode) {
                Dummy_Object__c dummyObj = new Dummy_Object__c();
                
                dummyObj.Account_Code__c = detObj.Lowest_Location_Hierarchy_Level_Code;
                dummyObj.Account_Desc__c = detObj.Lowest_Location_Hierarchy_Level_Description;
                dummyObj.SOH_Code__c = detObj.Lowest_SOH_Level_Code;
                dummyObj.SOH_Desc__c = detObj.Lowest_SOH_Level_Description;
                    
                accToTerrList.add(dummyObj);
            }
        }
        
        insert accToTerrList;
        System.debug('$$$Inserted Successfully ' + accToTerrList.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate the method with `@TestVisible`. Like so.

```
@TestVisible
private void insertRawData(LocationSOHMapSummary locSohMapObj) {
    ...
}
```